# Is there a way to "wrap on character" in the identify result box?

Tags: qgis

I have lists of plant species recorded at different sites (polygons). I have listed the species with their coverage in a seperate field. species seperated by semicolon. When showing the information of the polygon "identify results" the list is cut (see picture).

Is there a way to wrap the list on character to get a list in vertical column alignment. Best would be after every second semicolon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is currently possible for the **Identify Features** window (atleast I haven't seen anything related). You can certainly do this with labels though.

Otherwise, you can always send a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) to the QGIS devs!