# Possible to use wordwrap in the identify features tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, identify

I was wondering if it is possible to change the appearance of the identify features tool in QGIS by applying wordwrap.

I have a field ("description") with multiple lines of information (up to 1000 characters) about archeological monuments. I would like to see these lines of text capped at 50 caracters with the reminder of the text continuing on the following lines whenever I click on an archeological monument.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188320/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-on-character-in-the-identify-result-box Apparently not just yet? You could use wordwrap in the tooltips field, and do all kinds of html styling to compensate, though it's not the same.